# How to retrieve Date from Core Data and set value in UIPicker

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode6, data-retrieval

I am writing an iOS application using xCode 6 and Objective-C. I am also using Core data to store strings, integer, and dates. I am trying to not only store data in core, but also retrieve/fetch them

I am having issues retrieving the value of an attribute in core data of type date (purchaseDate). I am getting the date using an `UIDatePicker` to get the date and then storing the date doing the following,

```
[newItem setValue:self.purchaseDate.date forKey:@"purchaseDate"];
```

where newItem is of type `NSManagedObject`;

This works without any issues.

Once stored, I am now trying to retrieve it when a user clicks on a given entry.  I retrieve the strings and integer without any issue whatsoever, but get an error when I try to retrieve the Date attribute (called purchaseDate).

I am trying something like the following which throws an exception,

```
// Set purchase date

[self.purchaseDate setValue:self.inventorydb forKey:@"purchaseDate"];
```

Note that the attribute in the class is called purchaseDate and is of type UIDatePicker while the attribute in core data is of type Date and is also called purchaseDate.

The exception I am getting is:

```
UIDatePicker setValue:forUndefinedKey this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key purchaseDate.
```

I have already done a clean, rebuild as well as remove the application from the iOS simulator to no avail.

I have been looking for other examples, but have not found anything that works. Any assistance in this regard is appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put your date in an NSDate first, and then do something like:

self.purchaseDate.date = theNSDate;

Here it seems like you are trying to put an object of type NSDate in your UIDatePicker as you fetch an NSDate but try to put it in self.purchaseDate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your suggestion, I tried the following which worked.

[self.purchaseDate setDate:[self.inventorydb valueForKey:@"purchaseDate"]];